# Artifactory - Add standby database

Tags: database, oracle, artifactory

In our current Artifactory storage.properties:

url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@artifp1:1521:artifp1a

Tomcat starts successfully. Next, I use Oracle Net connection descriptor in Table 8-3 Supported Database Specifiers (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm):

```
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))"
```

to add a standby DB:

```
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ARTIFS1.cn.ca)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ARTIFS2.cn.ca)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ARTIFS_PRIMARY)))"
```

but have the following error when I start Artifactory:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@3dc368c1 returned null for URL:"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@3dc368c1 returned null for URL:"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
at org.artifactory.storage.db.spring.ArtifactoryTomcatDataSource.getConnection(ArtifactoryTomcatDataSource.java:189) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.13.2.jar:na]
at org.artifactory.storage.db.DbServiceImpl.printConnectionInfo(DbServiceImpl.java:183) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.13.2.jar:na]
at org.artifactory.storage.db.DbServiceImpl.initDb(DbServiceImpl.java:86) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.13.2.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when I remove the double quote (").

Final url:

```
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(FAILOVER=on)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=50)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_HOST1_NAME)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_HOST2_NAME)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SERVICE_NAME)))
```